# Return result set based on result from joined table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am building a webstore like application on Laravel 4 and I've run into a bit of difficulty when building a query. I want to return a list of products, which have an active amount of stock.

Each item of stock is listed as its own set of data, as what I am selling (Tickets) all have an unique code attached and so I want to know which codes have been sold and which have not.

I want to be able to calculate how many tickets have remained unsold and also only list ticket groups as active if they have tickets left to be sold.

I was going to do a static query via my Products model which returns each product and then does a query to return all the codes they have, but it seems long winded and I'm sure laravel has a way to return result sets based upon an internal query. I'm just not sure how I would do this..

Hopefully this makes sense, I basically want a quick and efficient way of checking a products stock levels by querying the active Products and then querying their Active Ticket stock.

---

Some code snippets

```
// Check if the code is active
    public function scopeActive($query) {
        return $query->where('active', '=', 1);
    }
// Relationship to product
public function product() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Product', 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

I want to be able to grab all the products with active codes so I guess
$product->codes->product as we are checking each product has active code, then using the product object through them?

Answer (score 0):

My description probably wasn't very clear but I found out I could do what I wanted by grouping the result set by the product_id

In the end I did

```
return  ProductCode::where('active', '=', 1)
            ->groupBy('product_id')
            ->get();
```

Hopefully this might help someone who was looking - it's not the most efficient way of doing it but it works..